# CSS: position: absolute together with margin: auto for centering - How does that work?

Tags: html, css

I've seen that pattern for centering an element on a website in the code of someone else:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placebear.com/200/300" alt="picture-one" />
```

It works fine. No doubt !

**But I can not imagine what the CSS-code actually does.**

I've seen similar code in which positioning was used to extend an child element to the size of it's parent.

```css
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: lime;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

But here it makes no sense to me.

Can someone explain me how these first shown technique work?

**What the single properties do and how it finally accomplishes it's result?**

I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lime;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

It's because the image has its default width and height.

When you use

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

Element would get the window size and position the element inside of it.

```css
#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: lime;
}

#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

So, if you put position relative to #wrap, the position absolute #child will adjust to the parent.

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` allows you to set the distance of you element from the top, bottom, right and left from the edges of the whole page.

In the second example you have shown even thought the #wrap is set to a height of 800px the #child distance from each side of the page is set to be 0. So therefore it covers the whole page!

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

```css
#inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #000; border:1px solid #fff;
}

#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```